# Is there an upload limit when using Web Client in C#?

Tags: c#, webclient

Using UploadFile("upload.php", "POST", filePath) with WebClient anything over 4mb will not upload. The limit in PHP is set at 48mb. Is there I need to set in C# ?

Comment: Hi Rob, I saw your attempted edit to the answer below, I suggest opening a new question and if you need to and referencing this question and that you want to use the app.config instead of the web.config. There are several reasons for this, but your suggested amendment wouldn't receive as much attention because you have already accepted the answer below and the answer below does answer your question as currently worded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a default maxRequestLength set at 4MB in ASP.NET, you can change it in the web.config.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <!-- This will handle requests up to 1024MB (1GB) -->
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" timeout="3600" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The length is specified in KB in the config file. If you are using IIS there is an additional limit set at 4MB by IIS.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, I am new to C# ,is this the correct file to  amend,  App.config? not sure on how to find the Web.conf file.

Comment: @RobMinford I'd say ASP.NET isn't really suitable for a desktop app that's going to upload large files (assuming this can't be made into a web app), you have to modify machine.config (the entire computer config file located in C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/<Framerwork>/<Version>/Config) if you want to do this, meaning it'll only work on your machine. Otherwise if you're sticking with ASP.NET I would look at using some other options for file upload that will chunk the upload into 4MB or smaller segments.

Comment: Im sorry for sounding dumb but as i said I am very new to C# and the .net framework. I throught by using c# and wpf i am creating a desktop application, what is this difference between C#(.net) and ASP.net?

Comment: @RobMinford You are and that's fine, but .NET (my mistake I should have just said .NET above, ASP.NET refers to the web framework specifically) desktop apps are just not very good at doing the particular thing you want to do (upload large files from a desktop app). I would suggest looking up how to chunk an upload so it sends the whole file in multiple smaller chunks, there is no other way around this in .NET desktop apps. I'm pretty sure this will be on SO somewhere already too :)

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem. By changing the following in the php.ini

post_max_size = 40M

I had already changed the upload_max_filesize but was not aware of this other param which needed changing.

Comment: What is  php.ini? Is C sharp use  php.ini?