# Sending a string with special characters/symbols to PHP service through web POST

Tags: c#, php, string

I'm trying to send a long string through HTTP post using C# and the `WebClient`. This code works when the string does not contain any special characters/symbols, but fails when the string does:

```
        string stringtosend= File.ReadAllText("string.txt");

        using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            string address = myurl;
            byte[] postData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("texto"= + stringtosend); 
            webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*";
            webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage] = "ru-RU";
            webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "gzip, deflate";
            webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            webClient.UploadData(address, postData);
        }

    }
```

The service the file is being sent to is implemented in PHP. The PHP code is as follows:

```
//GUARDAR EL LOG
if ($texto_post != "" && $id_post != "" && $tarea_post == "klog") {
    $fp = fopen("klog.txt", 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $texto_post);
    fclose($fp);
    die();

}
```

I tried to encode with Base64 but it does not work for strings that contains special characters/symbols. The following sample file is around 10kb and fails: https://www.sendspace.com/file/b3i4vl

When I send a larger file (around 20kb) with only "asdasdasd" repeated, it succeeds. What is causing the file with the special characters to fail?

Comment: How large is large?

Comment: There is a limitation, see this post: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26941906/is-there-an-upload-limit-when-using-web-client-in-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26941906/is-there-an-upload-limit-when-using-web-client-in-c)

Comment: I really don't know... the .txt collect special symbols, Is it possible that a special symbol is breaking the request?

Comment: The file weighs less than that 4MB limitation. I start to think it's because of some special character, but I do not know how to fix it. I've tried it with EncodeURL but it has a size limit.

Comment: EncodeURL is for URL encoding only. It might help if you post a sample of the data you're trying to send, as well as some information about the service which you are sending it too. For example, is the service implemented in asp.net or another technology?

Comment: For example this is never sent: https://www.sendspace.com/file/b3i4vl

Comment: What means  do not works? Be specific about what error do you get. Also, I don't get you comment about Base64, it works for arbitrarily large data, but it only makes the matters worse, as it increases size by 33%.

Comment: Do not works because PHP dont save it, When the size is smaller it stores it...

Comment: So you're sending it to a PHP web service?

Comment: Yes, it a simply php code that which collects the data and stores it in a file

Comment: OK, well if you have that PHP code, post it too. Your problem could very well be on the server side and not your C# code. I would also test with files of various sizes with just plain characters to rule out special characters issue.

Comment: Ok! thanks you, this is my php code!:

Comment: http://pastebin.com/HrecqJCG

Comment: As you see the php simply uses Fwrite to write the post data in a file

Comment: And you check the request size limit on your PHP service? Have you checked whether the request is sent to the service in full and it is failing on the save `Fwrite` call? Try making your PHP service echo the data received instead of saving it to disk.

Comment: Adrian, I think that any simbol is breaking the POST petition, cause I send 20KB of "asdasdasd......" without problems....

Comment: Ok im testing and when I use the symbol "&" it doesnt work!!!

Answer (score 1):

There is a limitation on what you can upload by default, see this post:

[Is there an upload limit when using Web Client in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26941906/is-there-an-upload-limit-when-using-web-client-in-c)

You can change it in the web.config under the `<system.web>` section.

Comment: The file weighs less than 4MB, I think that's not why. It only weighs 10 kilobytes.

Comment: Have you tried using fiddler to capture the post data to try and troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: Yes but I cant found the http post data in fiddler... example of what I send: https://www.sendspace.com/file/b3i4vl

Answer (score 0):

You are not telling us the server where the services that receive this data is on.

IIS has a limit on how large the data can be. Above that limit it will reject. Apache probably has some limits too.

If it's IIS then change the `web.config` setting for the `<requestLimits>`. The attribute you are looking for is `maxAllowedContentLength`

You can also do this from the IIS console. More on this and limits [here](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits).

Comment: The file weighs less than 4MB, I think that's not why. It only weighs 10 kilobytes.

Comment: @Enirique Garcia: that's not near being big. What is the error server is returning?

Comment: the server dont return an error, the problem start when I send the symbol "&" ....

Comment: I've checked your C# code and apart from compile error in line with `GetBytes` (= should in under the string) it works with the log.txt file you've provided. You need to check the server side - there should be a log of this request being made

Comment: I've manually checked with only a single "&" in the file and it dont work... I think is because php is detecting that im changing the variable

Comment: @EnriqueGarcía & is a variable delimiter so if you send sth like this: texto=&texto2= the PHP (and any other server) will detect that you've send two variables. texto, text2 - that how it's specified. You need to encode those to %26

Comment: The problem is that the encode has a limit ... So I do not know what to use.

Comment: @EnriqueGarcía I do not understand. What limit encode has?